# Loading an HTML page in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to load an HTML page by using a URL. This is what I'm doing now to find the count of images on a page:

```
$html = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');

$count = 0;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (strcmp($tag->tagName, "img") == 0) {
        $count++;
    }
} 
echo $count;
```

I know this isn't an efficient way to do this, I just set it up as an example. Each time, count is 0. But there are images on the page. Which brings me to believe the page isn't loading right. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

> DOMDocument::loadHTML — Load HTML from a string

It's signature is quite clear about this, too:

```
public bool DOMDocument::loadHTML ( string $source [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

You could try using [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php), or simply get the markup of the given url using `file_get_contents` or a cURL request (whichever works best for you).

And *please* don't use the error-suppression operator `@` of ***death*** if something emits a notice/warning/error, there's a problem. Don't ignore it, fix it!

Comment: I actually fixed it just as I asked. But you're answer explains it a bit more. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Tag names in HTML are canonically in upper-case, however you can avoid the issue by using `strcasecmp` instead of `strcmp`.

Or avoid both problems by doing it properly:

```
$count = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->length;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as stated, I set this up to show that the page wasn't loading. I just figured it out 30 seconds ago by doing this `$html = file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/");` instead of just `$html = "http://stackoverflow.com/";`

Comment: @nick: cf my answer, where I explain that `DOMDocument::loadHTML` doesn't do urls and suggest 3 alternative approaches (including `file_get_contents`, alongside `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` and a cURL request)